# How set condition Jetbrains.Annotations for Task<TType>

Tags: c#, annotations, resharper, rider

I want to give to analyzer information about nullable or not item inside of Task.

For example:

```
[NotNull]
[CoolAttributeForTask]
public Task<object> DoHardWordAsync()
{
    return Task.FromResult(null);
}
```

In this case, I want to say to analyzer: "I know that item inside task can be null, analyze it, please".

How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[ItemCanBeNull]`/`[ItemNotNull]` attributes for collection-like types (e.g. `List<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`), task-like types (`Task<T>`, `ValueTask<T>`) and `Lazy<T>`.